# Spectral Radius proof

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Let A be a symmetric matrix with positive Eigenvalues.Proof that ρ(Α^4)=(ρ(Α))^4 where ρ is the spectral radius.**

How should i go about that?

I am kinda confused on how should i use the information i am given

Comment: Are you aware (or, can you prove) that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$, then $\lambda^k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$ for all positive integers $k$?

Comment: How would I go about that?And how could i use it?

Comment: Start with the definition of eigenvalue.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is easy to verify that $\lambda^{k}$ is an eigen value of $A^{k}$ if $\lambda $ is an eigen value of $A$. But this is not enough to find the spectral radius.

Comment: The spectral radius is the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue, @Kavi. So I think what I've hinted at is all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

The spectral radius formula is $\rho (A)=\lim \|A^{n}\|^{1/n}$. From this $\rho (A^{4})=\lim \|A^{4n}\|^{1/n}=(\lim \|A^{4n}\|^{1/4n})^{4}$ which is $\rho (A) ^{4}$. See Gelfand Formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius

Comment: I wasn't aware of this formula??We never talked about it in Uni.Thank you this worked.